# How to verify/check the database table that only 20 record belong to this groupname in button?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

I am using vb. I have an aspx page that contains a TextBox (`txtStudentName`), a DropBox (`dropdownlistGroupName`) and a save button.

```
student table
    StudentID StudentName GroupID
       1         ABC        1
       2         DEF        1
       3         GHI        2

Group table   
GroupID GroupName
    1           Pear
    2           Apple
    3           Strawberry
```

When I click on the `Save` button it will insert in student, saying that this student belongs to this group name.

But at the save button, how am I going to check / validate that this group name, for example Apple, will only have 20 students belong to the group. If the user clicks on saving the 21st student, it should display a message saying that the group is full.

I am not sure how to check with the database.

Hope someone can tell me what I should do, along with an example that is nice and easy for me understand.

Comment: I'm attempting to understand your requirements.  A given GroupID in STUDENT cannot have more than 20 records?

Comment: @DanNewhouse take example only 20 student in this student list have this groupID (1), so how should check that in my save button

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following determine the number of students in the group prior to inserting a new row in the student table:

```
int count;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Student] WHERE [GroupID] = @GroupID", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupID", groupId);
        connection.Open();
        count = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}

if (count > 20)
{
    // Display error message.
}
else
{
    // Insert row into Student table
}
```

Alternatively, you could insert the row into the Student table, then do a count and if the count is > 20 rollback the transaction and display a message.

Comment: @Diamond GeezeR i need to check in my student table, only 20 student can have this groupID , so how should i use your that statement in my button to against the database

Comment: @devilking I've modified the statement to reference the Student table instead of the Group table. Just wrap the statement in a SqlCommand object (for example) and send to the database. Then check the return value.

Comment: @Diamond GeezeR can show me an exmaple? thank a lot and how to going to check the count > 20 in the if statemtent...what i mean was how to call the count to the if statement..

Comment: @devilking I have edited the answer to show how you might go about querying the database. You will need to add the connection string for your database to the call to SqlConnection's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In your click event for the button, do a count from STUDENT for the GroupID that will be inserted.  If the count is > 19, display error, if the count is < 20, insert the record.

You could also not allow a given GroupID to be available for selection if there is already 20 or more records in STUDENT.  If you have GroupIDs populating a combo box for example, you could  alter the criteria for populating the combo box to only include GroupID having count < 20.

I would still check the count in STUDENT prior to insert even if I was only displaying GroupIDs with less than 20 records (at the time the combo box was populated), just in case a record is inserted by someone else after your combo box populated.